# Return Value in Sequelize to Calling Method

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize for my ExpressJS project.

I have this code in my model:

```
exports.findAll = () => {
    let data = [];
    Book.findAll().then(books => {
        data = books; // book has array of objects
    });

    return data; // but data doesn't have even after assigning books to data
};
```

I want method **findAll** to return value when called by the **BookController**.

Comment: because of the asynchronous nature of javascript, this code returns before it has a chance to assign value to data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning an asynchronous value synchronously, what you probably want to do in this case since sequelize returns a promise for the `findAll` method is

```
exports.findAll = () => {
  let data = [];
  return Book.findAll();
};
```

then in your controller assuming you have required the module as `BookService` and are in a list controller method, you can do this this to retrieve the books

```
list(req, res) {
 return BookService.findAll().then(books => {
    data = books; // book has array of objects
    console.log(data); // you have your books 
    return res.json(books);
  });
}
```